# What are the pitfalls of enabling RFC 5746 (TLS Renegotiation Indication Extension) on my webserver?

Tags: apache-2.2, tls

Is it okay to enable RFC 5746 (TLS Renegotiation Indication Extension) on my apache+openssl config?

What browsers / clients will I not be able to support if this extension is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

The notable exception is all versions of IE on Windows XP, which means those users will end up at the default name-based vhost (with whatever cert it happens to have).

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Comment: This question is about the renegotiation extension ([RFC 5746](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5746)), not the server name indication extension ([RFC 3546](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3546) and its successors).